# Redirect 301 not working using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying redirect a url which has move to another one using 301 redirect. Below is the code which doesn't seems to work:

```
RewriteEngine On
Redirect /abc/def/ http://my-site.com/ghi/jkl.php
```

It gives 404 error.

Comment: Does **/ghi/jkl.php** exist?

Comment: @Starkeen Yes it does. The redirection doesn't even takes place, in the url I can only see http://my-site.com/abc/def/ in place of http://my-site.com/ghi/jkl.php

Comment: Try going to the urltwith with a trailing slash.

Comment: @Starkeen Not working

Answer (score 1):

You have to have `mod_rewrite` installed, and make sure Apache allows `.htaccess` files.

Install and enable `mod_rewrite`. Otherwise the `RewriteEngine On` is not understood by Apache.

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Allow Overrides, otherwise Apache ignores the `.htaccess` file in your dierctory. In your Apache configuration (probably in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/your-site.conf or somewhere in /etc/httpd/), make sure that your vhost has *not* `AllowOverride None` set. The default is `AllowOverride All`.

Comment: He is using mod_alias to redirect his url.